# Making TMPro shader compatible with LWRP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In my unity Project, here is the code for TMpro shader:

```
Shader "TextMeshPro/Distance Field" {

Properties {
    _FaceTex            ("Face Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _FaceUVSpeedX       ("Face UV Speed X", Range(-5, 5)) = 0.0
    _FaceUVSpeedY       ("Face UV Speed Y", Range(-5, 5)) = 0.0
    _FaceColor          ("Face Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _FaceDilate         ("Face Dilate", Range(-1,1)) = 0

    _OutlineColor       ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
    _OutlineTex         ("Outline Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _OutlineUVSpeedX    ("Outline UV Speed X", Range(-5, 5)) = 0.0
    _OutlineUVSpeedY    ("Outline UV Speed Y", Range(-5, 5)) = 0.0
    _OutlineWidth       ("Outline Thickness", Range(0, 1)) = 0
    _OutlineSoftness    ("Outline Softness", Range(-1,1)) = 0

    _Bevel              ("Bevel", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _BevelOffset        ("Bevel Offset", Range(-0.5,0.5)) = 0
    _BevelWidth         ("Bevel Width", Range(-.5,0.5)) = 0
    _BevelClamp         ("Bevel Clamp", Range(0,1)) = 0
    _BevelRoundness     ("Bevel Roundness", Range(0,1)) = 0

    _LightAngle         ("Light Angle", Range(0.0, 6.2831853)) = 3.1416
    _SpecularColor      ("Specular", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _SpecularPower      ("Specular", Range(0,4)) = 2.0
    _Reflectivity       ("Reflectivity", Range(5.0,15.0)) = 10
    _Diffuse            ("Diffuse", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Ambient            ("Ambient", Range(1,0)) = 0.5

    _BumpMap            ("Normal map", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _BumpOutline        ("Bump Outline", Range(0,1)) = 0
    _BumpFace           ("Bump Face", Range(0,1)) = 0

    _ReflectFaceColor   ("Reflection Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
    _ReflectOutlineColor("Reflection Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
    _Cube               ("Reflection Cubemap", Cube) = "black" { /* TexGen CubeReflect */ }
    _EnvMatrixRotation  ("Texture Rotation", vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)


    _UnderlayColor      ("Border Color", Color) = (0,0,0, 0.5)
    _UnderlayOffsetX    ("Border OffsetX", Range(-1,1)) = 0
    _UnderlayOffsetY    ("Border OffsetY", Range(-1,1)) = 0
    _UnderlayDilate     ("Border Dilate", Range(-1,1)) = 0
    _UnderlaySoftness   ("Border Softness", Range(0,1)) = 0

    _GlowColor          ("Color", Color) = (0, 1, 0, 0.5)
    _GlowOffset         ("Offset", Range(-1,1)) = 0
    _GlowInner          ("Inner", Range(0,1)) = 0.05
    _GlowOuter          ("Outer", Range(0,1)) = 0.05
    _GlowPower          ("Falloff", Range(1, 0)) = 0.75

    _WeightNormal       ("Weight Normal", float) = 0
    _WeightBold         ("Weight Bold", float) = 0.5

    _ShaderFlags        ("Flags", float) = 0
    _ScaleRatioA        ("Scale RatioA", float) = 1
    _ScaleRatioB        ("Scale RatioB", float) = 1
    _ScaleRatioC        ("Scale RatioC", float) = 1

    _MainTex            ("Font Atlas", 2D) = "white" {}
    _TextureWidth       ("Texture Width", float) = 512
    _TextureHeight      ("Texture Height", float) = 512
    _GradientScale      ("Gradient Scale", float) = 5.0
    _ScaleX             ("Scale X", float) = 1.0
    _ScaleY             ("Scale Y", float) = 1.0
    _PerspectiveFilter  ("Perspective Correction", Range(0, 1)) = 0.875

    _VertexOffsetX      ("Vertex OffsetX", float) = 0
    _VertexOffsetY      ("Vertex OffsetY", float) = 0

    _MaskCoord          ("Mask Coordinates", vector) = (0, 0, 32767, 32767)
    _ClipRect           ("Clip Rect", vector) = (-32767, -32767, 32767, 32767)
    _MaskSoftnessX      ("Mask SoftnessX", float) = 0
    _MaskSoftnessY      ("Mask SoftnessY", float) = 0

    _StencilComp        ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
    _Stencil            ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
    _StencilOp          ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
    _StencilWriteMask   ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
    _StencilReadMask    ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

    _ColorMask          ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
}

    HLSLINCLUDE
    #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
    ENDHLSL


    SubShader {


        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" "RenderPipeline" = "LightweightPipeline" }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        ZWrite Off
    Stencil
    {
        Ref [_Stencil]
        Comp [_StencilComp]
        Pass [_StencilOp] 
        ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
        WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
    }

    Cull [_CullMode]
    ZWrite Off
    Lighting Off
    Fog { Mode Off }
    ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
    Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
    ColorMask [_ColorMask]

    Pass {
    Tags { "LightMode" = "Lightweight2D" }
        CGPROGRAM 
        #pragma prefer_hlslcc gles
        #pragma target 3.0      

        #pragma multi_compile_instancing
        #pragma vertex VertShader
        #pragma fragment PixShader
        #pragma shader_feature __ BEVEL_ON
        #pragma shader_feature __ UNDERLAY_ON UNDERLAY_INNER
        #pragma shader_feature __ GLOW_ON

        #pragma multi_compile __ UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
        #pragma multi_compile __ UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP

        #pragma multi_compile _ _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS
        #pragma multi_compile _ _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_CASCADE
        #pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS_VERTEX _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS
        #pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHT_SHADOWS
        #pragma multi_compile _ _SHADOWS_SOFT
        #pragma multi_compile _ _MIXED_LIGHTING_SUBTRACTIVE



        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        #include "UnityUI.cginc"
        #include "TMPro_Properties.cginc"
        #include "TMPro.cginc"

        struct vertex_t {
            float4  position        : POSITION;
            float3  normal          : NORMAL;
            fixed4  color           : COLOR;
            float2  texcoord0       : TEXCOORD0;
            float2  texcoord1       : TEXCOORD1;
        };


        struct pixel_t {
            float4  position        : SV_POSITION;
            fixed4  color           : COLOR;
            float2  atlas           : TEXCOORD0;        // Atlas
            float4  param           : TEXCOORD1;        // alphaClip, scale, bias, weight
            float4  mask            : TEXCOORD2;        // Position in object space(xy), pixel Size(zw)
            float3  viewDir         : TEXCOORD3;

        #if (UNDERLAY_ON || UNDERLAY_INNER)
            float4  texcoord2       : TEXCOORD4;        // u,v, scale, bias
            fixed4  underlayColor   : COLOR1;
        #endif
            float4 textures         : TEXCOORD5;
        };

        // Used by Unity internally to handle Texture Tiling and Offset.
        float4 _FaceTex_ST;
        float4 _OutlineTex_ST;

        pixel_t VertShader(vertex_t input)
        {
            float bold = step(input.texcoord1.y, 0);

            float4 vert = input.position;
            vert.x += _VertexOffsetX;
            vert.y += _VertexOffsetY;

            float4 vPosition = UnityObjectToClipPos(vert);

            float2 pixelSize = vPosition.w;
            pixelSize /= float2(_ScaleX, _ScaleY) * abs(mul((float2x2)UNITY_MATRIX_P, _ScreenParams.xy));
            float scale = rsqrt(dot(pixelSize, pixelSize));
            scale *= abs(input.texcoord1.y) * _GradientScale * 1.5;
            if (UNITY_MATRIX_P[3][3] == 0) scale = lerp(abs(scale) * (1 - _PerspectiveFilter), scale, abs(dot(UnityObjectToWorldNormal(input.normal.xyz), normalize(WorldSpaceViewDir(vert)))));

            float weight = lerp(_WeightNormal, _WeightBold, bold) / 4.0;
            weight = (weight + _FaceDilate) * _ScaleRatioA * 0.5;

            float bias =(.5 - weight) + (.5 / scale);

            float alphaClip = (1.0 - _OutlineWidth*_ScaleRatioA - _OutlineSoftness*_ScaleRatioA);

        #if GLOW_ON
            alphaClip = min(alphaClip, 1.0 - _GlowOffset * _ScaleRatioB - _GlowOuter * _ScaleRatioB);
        #endif

            alphaClip = alphaClip / 2.0 - ( .5 / scale) - weight;

        #if (UNDERLAY_ON || UNDERLAY_INNER)
            float4 underlayColor = _UnderlayColor;
            underlayColor.rgb *= underlayColor.a;

            float bScale = scale;
            bScale /= 1 + ((_UnderlaySoftness*_ScaleRatioC) * bScale);
            float bBias = (0.5 - weight) * bScale - 0.5 - ((_UnderlayDilate * _ScaleRatioC) * 0.5 * bScale);

            float x = -(_UnderlayOffsetX * _ScaleRatioC) * _GradientScale / _TextureWidth;
            float y = -(_UnderlayOffsetY * _ScaleRatioC) * _GradientScale / _TextureHeight;
            float2 bOffset = float2(x, y);
        #endif

            // Generate UV for the Masking Texture
            float4 clampedRect = clamp(_ClipRect, -2e10, 2e10);
            float2 maskUV = (vert.xy - clampedRect.xy) / (clampedRect.zw - clampedRect.xy);

            // Support for texture tiling and offset
            float2 textureUV = UnpackUV(input.texcoord1.x);
            float2 faceUV = TRANSFORM_TEX(textureUV, _FaceTex);
            float2 outlineUV = TRANSFORM_TEX(textureUV, _OutlineTex);

            pixel_t output = {
                vPosition,
                input.color,
                input.texcoord0,
                float4(alphaClip, scale, bias, weight),
                half4(vert.xy * 2 - clampedRect.xy - clampedRect.zw, 0.25 / (0.25 * half2(_MaskSoftnessX, _MaskSoftnessY) + pixelSize.xy)),
                mul((float3x3)_EnvMatrix, _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, vert).xyz),
            #if (UNDERLAY_ON || UNDERLAY_INNER)
                float4(input.texcoord0 + bOffset, bScale, bBias),
                underlayColor,
            #endif
                float4(faceUV, outlineUV),
            };

            return output;
        }


        fixed4 PixShader(pixel_t input) : SV_Target
        {
            float c = tex2D(_MainTex, input.atlas).a;

        #ifndef UNDERLAY_ON
            clip(c - input.param.x);
        #endif

            float   scale   = input.param.y;
            float   bias    = input.param.z;
            float   weight  = input.param.w;
            float   sd = (bias - c) * scale;

            float outline = (_OutlineWidth * _ScaleRatioA) * scale;
            float softness = (_OutlineSoftness * _ScaleRatioA) * scale;

            half4 faceColor = _FaceColor;
            half4 outlineColor = _OutlineColor;

            faceColor.rgb *= input.color.rgb;

            faceColor *= tex2D(_FaceTex, input.textures.xy + float2(_FaceUVSpeedX, _FaceUVSpeedY) * _Time.y);
            outlineColor *= tex2D(_OutlineTex, input.textures.zw + float2(_OutlineUVSpeedX, _OutlineUVSpeedY) * _Time.y);

            faceColor = GetColor(sd, faceColor, outlineColor, outline, softness);

        #if BEVEL_ON
            float3 dxy = float3(0.5 / _TextureWidth, 0.5 / _TextureHeight, 0);
            float3 n = GetSurfaceNormal(input.atlas, weight, dxy);

            float3 bump = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap, input.textures.xy + float2(_FaceUVSpeedX, _FaceUVSpeedY) * _Time.y)).xyz;
            bump *= lerp(_BumpFace, _BumpOutline, saturate(sd + outline * 0.5));
            n = normalize(n- bump);

            float3 light = normalize(float3(sin(_LightAngle), cos(_LightAngle), -1.0));

            float3 col = GetSpecular(n, light);
            faceColor.rgb += col*faceColor.a;
            faceColor.rgb *= 1-(dot(n, light)*_Diffuse);
            faceColor.rgb *= lerp(_Ambient, 1, n.z*n.z);

            fixed4 reflcol = texCUBE(_Cube, reflect(input.viewDir, -n));
            faceColor.rgb += reflcol.rgb * lerp(_ReflectFaceColor.rgb, _ReflectOutlineColor.rgb, saturate(sd + outline * 0.5)) * faceColor.a;
        #endif

        #if UNDERLAY_ON
            float d = tex2D(_MainTex, input.texcoord2.xy).a * input.texcoord2.z;
            faceColor += input.underlayColor * saturate(d - input.texcoord2.w) * (1 - faceColor.a);
        #endif

        #if UNDERLAY_INNER
            float d = tex2D(_MainTex, input.texcoord2.xy).a * input.texcoord2.z;
            faceColor += input.underlayColor * (1 - saturate(d - input.texcoord2.w)) * saturate(1 - sd) * (1 - faceColor.a);
        #endif

        #if GLOW_ON
            float4 glowColor = GetGlowColor(sd, scale);
            faceColor.rgb += glowColor.rgb * glowColor.a;
        #endif

        // Alternative implementation to UnityGet2DClipping with support for softness.
        #if UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
            half2 m = saturate((_ClipRect.zw - _ClipRect.xy - abs(input.mask.xy)) * input.mask.zw);
            faceColor *= m.x * m.y;
        #endif

        #if UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP
            clip(faceColor.a - 0.001);
        #endif

        return faceColor * input.color.a;
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}

Fallback "TextMeshPro/Mobile/Distance Field"
CustomEditor "TMPro.EditorUtilities.TMP_SDFShaderGUI"
}
```

But in some devices, I have trouble with this shader when using LWRP.
Any TextMeshPro object that's in world space get's all in one position when I use LWRP. HUD elements work just fine:

[image]

The texts in the center of screen each should be on the white space of airplanes. If I switch the shader on my font mat to LWRP shaders they work as normal, except they look horrible.

When I try to upgrade the font material I get :

> material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert
>   TextMeshPro/Distance Field shader to selected pipeline

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is extremely challenging, I'm sure there's a few people working on this at Unity HQ. For 2D games, I don't believe LWRP has anything to offer over Forward rendering, are you sure you need it?

Comment: @DoctorPangloss
i need lighting in my 2D Game. so yes i really need this to work...

Comment: The problem has fixed by updating to unity version 2019.2.16 and updating LWRP plugin...